# Optimizing efficiency for implementation in tensorflow decorated function (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a 50000x32x32x3 array of training images which will be compared against a base image (32x32x3).  This code works for calculating [delta C](https://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm) , however ,its very inefficient:

```
squared_diffs = (train_images - base)**2
rBar = (train_images + base)/2
DeltaC = np.zeros((50000,32, 32))

for i in range(len(blankC)):
        for j in range(len(blankC[i])):
            for k in range(len(blankC[j])):
                DeltaC[i][j][k] = np.sqrt((2*squared_diffs[i][j][k][0]) + (4*squared_diffs[i][j][k][1]) +\
                            (3*squared_diffs[i][j][k][2]) + (rBar[i][j][k][0]*(squared_diffs[i][j][k][0]-squared_diffs[i][j][k][2])))
```

This results in a 50000x32x32 array which is what I want.  My goal is to calculate delta C in a tensorflow decorated function.
The 4D array is difficult for me to navigate properly, any help making this more Pythonic would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
squared_diffs = (train_images - base)**2
squared_diffs0 = squared_diffs[:,:,:,0]
squared_diffs1 = squared_diffs[:,:,:,1]
squared_diffs2 = squared_diffs[:,:,:,2]
rBar = (train_images + base)/2
rBar = rBar[:,:,:,0]
DeltaC = np.sqrt((2*squared_diffs0) + (4*squared_diffs1) + (3*squared_diffs2) + (rBar*(squared_diffs0-squared_diffs2)))
```